Marshmallow Flask Python pass path parameters to Schema for handling logic of body parameters
I am trying to validate some body params with the help of the path params as I have several types of Orders.
Is there a way for passing some arguments, like the path parameters (commodity and day), to the load method or to a pre_load method or to a constructor of the Schema CreateOrder class ?
@app.route('/orders/<commodity>/<day>/<user>/send_to_trading', methods=['POST'])
def send_mail(commodity, day, user):
    # validating the fields of this order
    try:
        req_params = create_order.load(request.json, many=True)
    except ValidationError as e:
        abort(HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, description=e)
    ...

class CreateOrder(Schema):

    quantity = fields.Float(required=True)
    price = fields.Float(required=False, dump_default='', allow_none=True)
    ...
    commodity = ? # path param

    @validates_schema
    def validate_fields(self, data, **kwargs):
        if data['price'] == '':
            raise ValidationError(PRICE_IS_MISSING)

    @validates_schema
    def validate_fields(self, data, **kwargs):
        if data['commodity'] == 'type1':
            if data['srcmarket'] == ''
                raise ValidationError(SHOULD_NOT_BE_EMPTY)
        elif data['commodity'] == 'type2':
            if data['srcmarket'] != ''
                raise ValidationError(SHOULD_BE_EMPTY)
        ...

create_order = CreateOrder()

An example of body parameters would look like:
{"price":1, "power":1}


why not include it in the json simply with request.json["commodity"] = commodity before your load function?

Because I have a long list of body parameters and was trying to remove some of them as they are already present as path parameters. But I am currently using as a temporary fix your solution. Thanks !
